# multiprocessing do not work in USB

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

Hello, This simple codes come from multiprocessing document.

I tried to run this in Spyder IDE, and It worked.

and, I saved this file in my USB and, I tried it exactly same way.

but it didn't work.

I don't know why..

Is this about Computer structure??

Comment: what do you mean " I saved this file in my USB and, I tried it exactly same way."? It didnt work, what happen post an error log

Comment: I mean I just run this code.there is no different.  Ah actually. No error. Infinite loop.

Comment: How do you know its an infinite loop? What system are you on and how do you execute the script? There may be permission restrictions that keep you from executing it. Its also possible that you are running a different script than you think you are. You could add `import os;print(os.path.abspath(__file__))` to the script, run it and then verify that is the right file.

Comment: as your mention, I added the statements, and I checked that it is right file. yes. this is the file that I want to run..   
Umm.. I can get right output without waiting. but IN USB CONDITION, It was running for 10 or more minutes. so I think this was infinite loop.